# how to run jar file assgin to variable and echo it out in shell script

Tags: java, linux, shell, jar

I am trying to run a jar file in a shell script. And I want to assign the out put of that jar file and echo it out. I tried something like below.

```
#!/bin/bash

$the_output = "$(java -jar portalOutputFormater.jar $1 $2 $3 $4  2>&1 )"

echo the_output
```

My java program returns the output as 'output=var1_var2_var3_var4" for the four input parameters.
But I am getting the output as..

```
portaloutputformatter.sh: line 3: =output=var1_var2_var3_var4: command not found
```

What I am I doing wrong here? I just need to run my jar file then assign it to variable and output the variable.

Thank You !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your bash syntax is all wrong. Here's a quick fix, but you do need to start learning some basics...

```
#!/bin/bash

the_output=$(java -jar portalOutputFormater.jar $1 $2 $3 $4 2>&1)

echo $the_output
```