# Run bash script loop in background which will write result of jar command to file

Tags: bash, shell, executable-jar

I'm novice to running bash script. (you can suggest me, if title I've given is incorrect.)
I want to run a jar file using bash script in loop. Then it should write the output of jar command into some file.
Bash file **datagenerate.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Total iterations are 500
for i in {1..500}
do
   the_output="$(java -jar data-generator.jar 10 1 mockData.csv data_200GB.csv)"
   echo $the_output
   echo Iteration  $i processed
done
no_of_lines="$(wc -l data_200GB.csv)"
echo "${no_of_lines}"
```

I'm running above script using command `nohup sh datagenerate.sh > datagenerate.log &`. As I want to run this script in background, so that even I log out from `ssh` it should keep running & output should go into `datagenerate.log`.

But when I ran above command and hit enter or close the terminal it ends the process. Only `Total iterations are 500` is getting logged into output file.

Let me know what I'm missing. I followed following two links to create above shell script: [link-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20166919/how-to-run-jar-file-assgin-to-variable-and-echo-it-out-in-shell-script) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18612603/redirecting-output-of-bash-for-loop).

Comment: are you sure that your process is not continuing? you can run `ps -axjf` to view running processes. I think you java process is running but not printing anything (yet).

Comment: Yes.It's not continuing. I ran the command `nohup sh datagenerate.sh > datagenerate.log &`  & after 2 seconds I hit enter, then it's showing process is Done. I checked whether it's running & result was it didn't show any process with that id.
My java process is running & it's printing values.(I'm sure about it & verified as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> nohup sh datagenerate.sh > datagenerate.log &

nohup should work this way without using screen program, but depending on your distro your sh shell might be linked to dash.
Just make your script executable:

```
chmod +x datagenerate.sh
```

and run your command like this:

```
nohup ./datagenerate.sh > datagenerate.log &
```

Comment: It helped to keep the process running, but no logs are getting printed in `datagenerate.log`

Comment: Do you get a nohup.out? Because this way it only captures stdout, not stderr to datagenerate.log.

Comment: I'm not getting nohup.out. In `datagenerate.log` it's just printing `Total iterations are 500` but not the output & last line` echo`.

Comment: There is no error in the bash code. It runs for me and prints expected output for 500 iterations.

Comment: thanks, it's working. Actually there was some extra code in my bash, I fixed it.

Comment: You can quickly exchange long running process for a printf to check if the rest is working ok: Here, https://ideone.com/Hwza3I

Comment: `nohup ./datagenerate.sh > datagenerate.log &` will this work with ubuntu SSH EXEC?? @xenoson

Answer (score 0):

You should check this out:
https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen

With this programm you can close your shell while a command or script is still running. They will not be aborted and you can pick the session up again later.

Comment: This is again some new tool, I'm looking to get it done using simple bash script.